# Fill function on canvas returns error

Tags: java, graphics, paint, fill

I am currently developing and application that is a paint program. I am currently in the process of making the fill tool, but I have run into an error. I can't explain it in words, because I don't know why the error occurs, but here is the code that is used by the function and the log:

```
class FillerOperator {
public static BufferedImage bImg;
public boolean state = false;
public boolean isFinished()
{
    return state;
}
public FillerOperator (int x, int y, int RGB)
{
    state = true;

    bImg.setRGB(x, y, RGB);

    if(bImg.getRGB(x+1,y)==RGB)
    {
        state = false;
        new FillerOperator(x+1,y,RGB);
    }
    if(bImg.getRGB(x-1,y)==RGB)
    {
        state = false;
        new FillerOperator(x-1,y,RGB);
    }
    if(bImg.getRGB(x,y+1)==RGB)
    {
        state = false;
        new FillerOperator(x,y+1,RGB);
    }
    if(bImg.getRGB(x,y-1)==RGB)
    {
        state = false;
        new FillerOperator(x,y-1,RGB);
    }

}
}
```

where it is called:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if(JToolBar.getCurrentTool()=="fill")
    {           
        FillerOperator.bImg = unscaledImg;
        FillerOperator fo = new FillerOperator(e.getX(),e.getY(),JToolBar.getCurrentColor().getRGB());
        while(!fo.isFinished()){}//wait until it is finished.
        unscaledImg = FillerOperator.bImg;

    }
    repaint();
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: 1) which line in your code above throws the NPE? 2) bImg should definitely not be static. I'm thinking that you should pass it into your FillerOperator via a constructor parameter. 3) Where are you getting your unscaledImg from? 4) Are you sure that your unscaledImg is not null? I suspect that it likely is.

Comment: You are kind of right - unscaledImg is not null, but bImg is. I have no idea how to pass on the image and then retrieve it without it being static so I can retrieve it back

Comment: This is wrong: `if(JToolBar.getCurrentTool()=="fill")`. You should never use `==` to compare Strings, but rather the `equals(...)` method. You are fixing the wrong thing by making bImg static. Make it non-static and fix the code so static is not needed. You will need to create and post a [minimal, runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if we're to be able to help you, I think.